# I'm getting a 404 Error when I run a $http POST request with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, http-status-code-404

I am building an app which allows users to place bets in betting pools. When the user hits a button, a function in the controller is executed, but the requests isn't made and returns a 404 error, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
function placeBet(bet) {
console.log('in place bet');

$http.post('https://colossusdevtest.herokuapp.com/api/tickets.json', {
  'id': 550900,
  'status': 'PLACED',
  'customer_payout': '0.0',
  'stake': bet,
  'currency': 'GBP',
  'lines': 24,
  'amount_owned_customer': '1.0',
  'cost': '12.0',
  'created_at': '2015-07-23T17:00:10.000Z',
  'offer_amount': '0.0',
  'customer_winnings': '0.0',
  'offers_accepted': '0.0',
  'merchant_ref': '15ac9a2e-d4a8-4652-a60c-2b57d1afd92b',
  'pool': {
    'id': 171,
    'name': 'Mixed 4',
    'type_code': 'POINT_MARGIN',
    'headline_prize': '4996.06',
    'status': 'OPEN',
    'sched_start': '2015-07-28T11:00:00.000Z',
    'sched_next': '2015-07-28T11:00:00.000Z',
    'currency': 'GBP',
    'leg_num': 4,
    'sport_code': 'RUGBY',
    'has_offers': false
  }
}).then(() => {
  console.log('information posted');
});
}

$scope.placeBet = placeBet;
```

[Problem](https://i%60.stack.imgur.com/XjlJw.png%60)

Comment: Are you sure POST is possible? GET is working fine

Comment: Are you making a CORS request? If yes, is your heroku app set up to allow CORS requests?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image description.

There can be few options what can be wrong with your post call.
   - if you have correct url - yours finishing with json doesn't sound good
   - make sure that you have correct data
   - you may need config part for http.post.  [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)
   - add catch block after then to catch error
   - check if it's CORS issue

First make sure that you can connect to your server with Postman plugin for chrome then pack your call in angular http.post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change your code into:

```
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/someUrl',
  data: bet
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
});
```

Please ensure that your request doesn't cross domain request.